# jQuery Smooth Scrolling to anchor on different page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My jQuery smooth scroll works if an element is linked to an anchor on the same page but it does not smooth scroll when linked to an anchor on a different page.

Are there any obvious problems with my jQuery script?

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {

    // //////////////////////// Smooth Scroll To Specific Element On Page ////////////////////////

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a[href^="#"]').not('.carousel-control-prev').not('.carousel-control-next').bind('click.smoothscroll', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var hash = this.hash;

            jQuery('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: jQuery(hash).offset().top - 65
            }, 1500, function(){});
        });
    });

    //////////////////////// Smooth Scroll To Specific Element On Different Page ////////////////////////

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var urlHash = window.location.href.split("#")[1] || false;
        if (urlHash.length > 0)
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#' + urlHash).offset().top - 60
            }, 2500);
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following sample code provides the desired functionality:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var urlHash = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
    if (urlHash &&  $('#' + urlHash).length )
          $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: $('#' + urlHash).offset().top - 60
          }, 2500);
});
```

Please note that if the URL was already visited, the browser will automatically jump to the hash without displaying the animation, then to reproduce the behavior we would need to clear the cache, then a workaround could be implementing a clearing cache function if we intended to display the animation again.